# Improvement of delete method

Tags: c#, sql

I was wondering if there is a better way to code this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
   using (SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM table WHERE 
         (TestNumber = '" + testNumber + "')", connection)) {
      try
      {
         connection.Open();
         int recordExists = deletePolicyFromTdm.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();

         if(recordExists == 1)
            result.Append("Record has been deleted");
         else
           result.Append("Record does not exist");
      ...
```

Couple of assumptions:

- `testNumber` is unique and no duplicate records and was input tested, at least according to bus rules. So I realize that if more than one record is present the `if` statement won't work properly
- Table has a PK but `testNumber` isn't it
- Only one roundtrip to db
- Can't change how DB is set up
- SQL command will eventually be replaced with a sproc and parameter

The idea is that if user clicks a button and gets either a message that no record exists or that the records were deleted.

Answer (score 4):

A few quick remarks:

1. In your second `using` statement, you declare a `SqlCommand` variable named `cmdDelete`. In the body of that `using` statement, however, you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a variable named `deletePolicyFromTdm`. I don't see a declaration for `deletePolicyFromTdm` in your code, so I wonder if it should be `cmdDelete` instead.
2. I'm not sure where `testNumber` is coming from, but your approach potentially opens the door for SQL injection. I recommend defining it as a parameterized query (e.g. `DELETE FROM table WHERE TestNumber = @TestNumber`); it's a very small amount of work and will be one less thing to do when you switch to a sproc later.
3. Your brace style is not consistent. The braces following `using` are on the same line; the brace following `try` are on a separate line.

Comment: I appreciate taking then time to reply. I neglected to change the `deletePolicyFromTdm` as I didn't want to show actual name, so my bad. The testNumber is being passed as aparameter from a calling method and is passed through validation. The braces, while are inconsistent, don't really take away from effectivness and will a make the correction. My purpose for asking for a review was in regards to the `recordsExists` and how I check for records existance without making a separate data call to such as `SELECT COUNT(*)...`